# sorting int array with only 3 elements

Tags: algorithm, optimization, sorting, pseudocode

I have this array:

```
int [] myarray =  {17, 6, 8};
```

What is the optimal way to sort this array, in pseudocode?

Thanks!

Comment: `sorted(a)` with my pseudo `sorted` function that sorts in place :)

Comment: Many duplicates, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319993/sorting-the-three-integers-program

Comment: Easy: `int [] myarray = {6, 8, 17};` :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I think this should be quite fast (ascending order):

```
if (el1 > el2) Swap(el1,el2)
if (el2 > el3) Swap(el2,el3)
if (el1 > el2) Swap(el1,el2)
```

Comment: Your classic unrolled bubble sort :-) +1.

Answer (score 13):

This code makes 2 or 3 comparisons and 4 memory records in the worst case, as opposed to another answer (always 3 comparisons and 9 memory records in the worst case).

```
if a[0] < a[1]:
    if a[1] > a[2]:
        if a[0] < a[2]:
            temp = a[1]
            a[1] = a[2]
            a[2] = temp
        else:
            temp = a[0]
            a[0] = a[2]
            a[2] = a[1]
            a[1] = temp
    else:
        # do nothing
else:
    if a[1] < a[2]:
        if a[0] < a[2]:
            temp = a[0]
            a[0] = a[1]
            a[1] = temp
        else:
            temp = a[0]
            a[0] = a[1]
            a[1] = a[2]
            a[2] = temp
    else:
        temp = a[0]
        a[0] = a[2]
        a[2] = temp
```

Comment: I'll give you +1 for that, adamax. Though it's butt-ugly to read, the question _did_ ask for optimal and yours seems to satisfy that :-)

Comment: Your algorithm yields an incorrect result with {2, 3, 1} array.

Comment: @ionree Sure, I fixed the code. If you take a look at [the original code](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4795638/revisions), you'll see that execution path ends up swapping two elements while every element has to be moved.

Comment: Slight optimization: replacing the first `<` comparison with `=<` would avoid an unnecessary swap if `a[0]`==a[1]`.

Answer (score 13):

Slightly more efficient version than the unrolled bubble sort, not optimal, but still quite simple

```
if (el1 > el2) Swap(el1, el2)
if (el2 > el3) {
   Swap(el2, el3)
   if (el1 > el2) Swap(el1, el2)
}
```

Comment: I can't believe someone voted this down. It was at –1. I just upvoted it and now it's at 0.

Answer (score 6):

May [this graphic](http://wwwdh.cs.fau.de/IMMD8/Lectures/THINF3/Tagebuch0506/index.html) showing a decision tree for sorting three elements helps:
[image]

Comment: Which book is this from?

Comment: This is from "Grundlegende Algorithmen" (http://www14.in.tum.de/~ga/) by Volker Heun -- unfortunately in German only. A very similar figure can be found in "Introduction to Algorithms" by Cormen et al.(http://mitpress.mit.edu/books/introduction-algorithms).

Comment: I knew I'd seen it somewhere... perhaps it's in the Sedgewick book, too? But for anyone else wondering it is indeed in CLRS, under "Sorting in Linear Time." Thanks!